# Image source not readable on my localhost

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to upload images in dropzone from my localhost then I get ERROR! but on server I can upload this successful.This problem made me difficult to test product.

[image: [this is error]]

and this is my code

```
public function storeMedia(Request $request)
{
    //resize image
    $path = storage_path('tmp/uploads');
    $imgwidth = 1000;
    $imgheight = 1000;
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        mkdir($path, 775, true);
    }
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $name = uniqid() . '_' . trim($file->getClientOriginalName());
    $full_path = storage_path('tmp/uploads/' . $name);
    $img = \Image::make($file->getRealPath());
    if ($img->width() > $imgwidth || $img->height() > $imgheight) {
        $img->resize($imgwidth, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
    }
    $img->save($full_path);
}
```

I think maybe about permission but i'm not sure. I really don't know to solve this problem please help me

Comment: yes on my  local machine

Comment: Can you add your `form` code to your question too please?

Comment: Could you please make sure that you have added ```enctype="multipart/form-data"``` in your form.

Comment: this will help you... 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157824/intervention-image-upload-error-image-source-not-readable